# read dictionaries from file - python

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a series of dictionaries from a file:

GFG.txt

```
{'geek': 10, 'geeky': True}
{'GeeksforGeeks': 'Education', 'geekgod': 101.0, 3: 'gfg'}
{'supergeek': 5}
```

and I found this [website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/read-list-of-dictionaries-from-file-in-python/) with the following solution:

```
import pickle
geeky_file = open('GFG.txt', 'r')
dictionary_list = pickle.load(geeky_file)
  
for d in dictionary_list:
    print(d)
geeky_file.close()
```

However this throws an exception:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Opening the file in binary mode:

```
geeky_file = open('GFG.txt', 'rb')
```

gives me the error:

```
UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '{'.
```

Comment: you can load with pickle, if you have dumped with pickle. Who wrote that file format ?

Comment: like @azro said, you can't just write the dictionaries in plain text in the file. you need to use pickle to dump the dictionaries to a file and then you can use pickle to load those dictionaries from a file

Comment: You could in theory read each line as JSON, but that is invalid JSON. The problem here is you don't use a standard file format.

Answer (score 0):

If every "text dictionary" is on a single line, `ast.literal_eval` can help:

```py
import ast

with open('GFG.txt', 'rb') as f:
    list_of_dicts = [ast.literal_eval(line.decode()) for line in f]
list_of_dicts
```

Output:

```
[{'geek': 10, 'geeky': True},
 {'GeeksforGeeks': 'Education', 'geekgod': 101.0, 3: 'gfg'},
 {'supergeek': 5}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary), you can load each `dict` in to a new `dict` to access them by line number.

```
import ast

file_dicts = {}
with open('GFG.txt') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        file_dicts[i] = ast.literal_eval(line)
```

Result:

```
{0: {'geek': 10, 'geeky': True}, 1: {'GeeksforGeeks': 'Education', 'geekgod': 101.0, 3: 'gfg'}, 2: {'supergeek': 5}}
```